# Ajax Post request not authorized

Tags: ajax, ssl, cors

I have this webapp where I make a post request using Ajax from Domain A to a rest service on Domain B
Domain B has been set up to serve the response with the CORS Access-Control* headers in order to get the cross-domain posting to work

Headers in response from domain B:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:   true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:       content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:       POST GET OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:        https://sub.domain-a.com
Access-Control-Max-Age:             180
```

The Ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://sub.domain-b.com',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
    },
    data: json,
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
});
```

I am logged in on both domains and my request sends the necessary cookie (withCredentials=true), but I am still getting a 403 Forbidden from the response

Both domains are using SSL a certificate

I am beginning to wonder if the SSL's are causing the problem as this worked before and I am getting nothing in my logs

Are there anyone here that have any experience with something similar?
Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

It could be something similar to this issue: 
[Pre-flight OPTIONS request failing over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037686/pre-flight-options-request-failing-over-https/18757639#18757639)

Typically when the issue is with SSL and the preflight request though you wouldn't get back a 403, you'd just get the OPTIONS request aborting.

How does the service authenticate and authorise? Are you using self-signed certificates? It sounds like you're correct in thinking that SSL is causing the issue and without more info it's hard to say what your specific problem is.