# Force ssl certificate to be included in CORS pre-flight request

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, https, cors

I am trying to make a (non-simple) CORS GET request (AJAX) made by my client server (running on Apache @ port 443) to a 3rd party endpoint server (running on Tomcat @ port 8443), which fails to trigger when tried over HTTPS.

When SSL is not enabled it works just fine indicating that the CORS is set up properly.

The problem is that since the GET is (not-simple) it sends a pre-flight OPTIONS request.

According to this:
[Pre-flight OPTIONS request failing over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037686/pre-flight-options-request-failing-over-https)

Pre-flighted requests don't include the client certificate. He states this is in the CORS spec however I was unable to find this specifically listed in the spec:
http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

The third party cannot enable

```
SSLVerifyClient optional
```

as they require all communication be sent with SSL.

However they do have their CORS setup right and they have

```
access-control-allow-credentials: "true"
```

In our AJAX call we included in the xhrFields

```
  withCredentials: true
```

So we are telling it to pass withCredentials (which includes cert / cookie / etc)

And on our APACHE we have

```
SSLOptions +ExportCertData
```

Somehow when we make the call though, they are still seeing the error "key/cert was not included "

Am I missing something? Is there a way to force this in Apache? 
At the moment I'm getting ready to create a man the middle script to attach the cert to the initial request but it seems like there has to be a better way.

Any suggestions?